# Monit cannot open connection errors resulting in alerts from M/Monit that server is down

Tags: monit

I'm using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) and [M/Monit](http://mmonit.com/) to monitor my application infrastructure. But every once in a while, M/Monit will show a "No report" error from a server and mark it down. A few seconds later, the issue clears at the next check in for the server to M/Monit.

The monit logs on some of the servers have these events in them:

> Oct 14 12:19:11 ip-10-203-51-199 monit[30307]: M/Monit: cannot open a
>   connection to http://example.com:8080/collector -- Connection timed out
>
> Oct 14 12:20:16 ip-10-203-51-199 monit[30307]: M/Monit: cannot open a
>   connection to http://example.com:8080/collector -- Connection timed out
>
> Oct 14 12:22:21 ip-10-203-51-199 monit[30307]: M/Monit: cannot open a
>   connection to http://example.com:8080/collector -- Connection timed out

What config do I need to tune to increase the threshold until M/Monit considers the server actually down?

Here is the config from the server that has the most trouble:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
  allow xxx:xxx
set mailserver xxx.xxx.xxx port xxx username "xxx" password "xxx" using tlsv1 with timeout 15 seconds
set daemon 30
     with start delay 120
set logfile syslog facility log_daemon
set alert xxx
set mail-format {
  subject: $EVENT $SERVICE on $HOST
  from: monit@$HOST
  message: Monit $ACTION $SERVICE at $DATE on $HOST: $DESCRIPTION.
}
set mmonit http://xxx:xxx@example.com:8080/collector
```

Comment: Could you share the configuration file or how often m/monit polls?

Comment: Edited the question to include config.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any problem with config file.
The intermittent problem you are experiencing is because monit is failing to open a socket on the port and timing out. See the source code for reference (handle_mmonit()):
http://fossies.org/linux/privat/monit-5.6.tar.gz:a/monit-5.6/src/collector.c

Search for the string "M/Monit: cannot open a connection to".

The timeout value appears to be fixed at 5 seconds in the code. But 5 seconds is ample time to open a socket connection on that port.

How often does monit post events to mmonit?

Comment: I *think* it posts every 30 seconds, per the set daemon 30 statement in the config.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem

```
[MST Apr  5 11:24:11] error    : 'apache' failed protocol test [APACHESTATUS] at [phoenix.example.com]:80 [TCP/IP] -- APACHE-STATUS: error -- no scoreboard found
[MST Apr  5 11:24:16] error    : Cannot create socket to [10x.xx.xx.x4]:8080 -- Connection timed out
```

We had another firewall on top of iptables.  Opened up the 8080 in the input and the output side and it fixed it!